# How to reference ASP.Net Identity User Email property as Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Trying to reference the Email property of an ASP.Net Identity User as a Foreign Key but keep getting an error message

using MVC6, EF7

I have an `AppAccount` which is the Primary model and the `ApplicationUser: IdentityUser` is the dependant.

I'm trying to set the `Email` property of the `ApplicationUser` as a foreign key the `AppAccount` model

```
public class AppAccount
{
    public string AppAccountID { get; set; }

    public string AccountType { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }

}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public virtual AppAccount AppAccount { get; set; }

}
```

'Peeking' to the definition of the IdentityUser tells me the Email property is of type string...

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    ...
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the email address for this user.
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
...
}
```

I have set the PK of the `AppAccount` Model to string and made the `Email` property of the `ApplicationUser` an Alternate key, then set a One-To-One relationship using fluent API...

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(au =>
            {
                au.HasAlternateKey(u => u.Email);
                au.HasAlternateKey(u => u.UserName);    
            });

        builder.Entity<AppAccount>(aa =>
        {
            aa.HasKey(a => a.AppAccountID);
            aa.HasOne(a => a.AppUser)
            .WithOne(u => u.AppAccount)
            .HasPrincipalKey<ApplicationUser>(u => u.Email);  // PK of AppAccount is FK of AppUser
        });
```

When I run the migration it works ok but when I try to update the database I get the following error

```
Error Number:1753,State:0,Class:16
Column 'AspNetUsers.Email' is not the same length or scale as 
referencing column 'AppAccount.AppAccountID' 
in foreign key 'FK_AppAccount_ApplicationUser_AppAccountID'. 
Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must 
be defined with the same length and scale.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I have tried manually setting the maximum length of the `AppAccountID` and `Email` properties to the same limit

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(au =>
            {
                ...
                au.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(100);    
            });

builder.Entity<AppAccount>(aa =>
        {
            ...
            aa.Property(a => a.AppAccountID).HasMaxLength(100);
            ...
        });
```

I have tried setting both properties to the same type on the server...

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(au =>
            {
                ...
                au.Property(u => u.Email).ForSqlServerHasColumnType("nvarchar(100)");    
            });

builder.Entity<AppAccount>(aa =>
        {
            ...
            aa.Property(a => a.AppAccountID).ForSqlServerHasColumnType("nvarchar(100)");
            ...
        });
```

tried overriding the `Email` property in the `ApplicationUser` class to

```
public override string Email {get ; set ;}
```

and I tried setting the `AppAccountID` property of the `AppAccount` Model to `virtual`

```
`public virtual string AppAccountID {get ; set ;}
```

I think this may be a server issue but checking the database the `Email` column type is nvarchar, so I dont understand why it doesnt compile?

Comment: As the error suggests, check if the email has a length attribute defined in model

Comment: `Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must 
be defined with the same length and scale` means that you need to examine the foreign relationship, data type and certainly length of linked columns. Also you may try `HasForeignKey` inside `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: @LibinJoseph - No length attribute defned in model that I can see, tried overriding the length attribute on previous attempts to resolve issue to no effect.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - Tried using `HasForeignKey` inside `OnModelCreating` as suggested but still receive same error. still looking for FK and data type discrepencies...

Comment: @Scheeeve I cant reproduce this -  it works for me if I set same length (`HasMaxLength(x)`).
Are you adding your customizations after calling `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` inside `OnModelCreating` method?

Comment: @tmg - Yep, definately adding customisation in right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies all, its amateur hour

Firstly I was writing `HasPrincipleKey` instead of `HasForeignKey` as pointed out by @TetsuyaYamamoto (Thankyou).

Secondly, after checking the database for the umpteenth time, the `Email` property for `ApplicationUser` is of type `NVARCHAR(256)`, so updating the customisation as below allowed EF to compile the model successfully.

```
builder.Entity<AppAccount>(aa =>
        {
            aa.HasKey(a => a.AppAccountID);
            aa.Property(a => a.AppAccountID).ForSqlServerHasColumnType("NVARCHAR(256)");
            aa.HasOne(a => a.AppUser)
            .WithOne(u => u.AppAccount)
            .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUser>(u => u.Email);
        });
```

Thanks all...this is why you don't code at 1 in the morning

Answer (score 0):

Try this Model

```
public class AppAccount
{
public string AppAccountID { get; set; }

public string AccountType { get; set; }

public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")
public virtual ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Adding `[ ForeignKey ("UserId")]` annotation would have pointed the FK relationship to the wrong column. I did try adding `ForeignKey ("Email")]` to the model but still received the same error when trying to update the database